# How to pass a result of a function in an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to hash a base64 to a base16 and put the result into a kvp array. Here my code (the base64 used here is hypothetical, it's to show you the problem) :

```js
async function hashData() {

    let base64 = 'sertyuiopnbv58426931';
    let hash = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256',  _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64));
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hash));         
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''); 
    console.log(hashHex);
    return hashHex;
}

function _base64ToArrayBuffer(mybase64) {
    let binary_string = window.atob(mybase64);
    let len = binary_string.length;
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}

function GetClubData () {

    let kvp = {};
    kvp['picture'] = hashData();

    let kvp2 = {};
    kvp2['Club'] = kvp;
    
    var json = JSON.stringify(kvp2,null," ");
    
    console.log(json);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <title> Test </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css"/>
</head>

<body>
  
  <button onclick="GetClubData()" > Get Club Data </button>
      
  <script src="../mylibrary/js/updateClub.js"></script>
</body>
```

In my console there is no 'picture' result. Any idea ?

Comment: `onclick="GetClubData"` — You have to **call** the function.

Comment: Yes I missed to write it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your hashData function is an async function and you have to write awite if you want to access the returned value like this

```
function GetClubData () {
    putInArray();
}

async function putInArray() {
    let kvp = {};
    kvp['picture'] = await hashData();

    let kvp2 = {};
    kvp2['Club'] = kvp;
    
    var json = JSON.stringify(kvp2,null," ");
    console.log(json)
}
```

Comment: I have this in console when I try : Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: @LauraBossy You'll need to wrap your code in a top level async function

Comment: @LauraBossy You have toto wrap your code in a top level async function i edited my code !

Answer (score 0):

`hashData` is an async function, which you need to await. The value in your "kvp" is a Promise, which cannot be JSON serialized by default.

Comment: So I cannot use an async function here ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to use the result of an async function `hashData` inside the normal function `GetClubData`. You cannot do this. To fix it, make the function `GetClubData` async and await the result of the async function `hashData`. Here's the correct code,

```js
async function GetClubData () {

    let kvp = {};
    kvp['picture'] = await hashData();

    let kvp2 = {};
    kvp2['Club'] = kvp;
    
    var json = JSON.stringify(kvp2,null," ");
    
    console.log(json);

}
```

Running the function `GetClubData` produces the result,

[image]

Also, call the function via `onclick` attribute,
`onclick="GetClubData()"`

Comment: That's not working for me, I should miss something, I will review my code to see what it is. But there is another way which works, thanks for your help :)

Comment: In fact it works but with onclick="GetClubData()"

Comment: Hi, that's right, it should be `onclick="GetClubData()`. I shall edit my answer (done).
Glad it helped you.